# Connecting to remote database located on web (freemysqlhosting.net‏) via visual studio c#

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have to connect my c# project to a remote database located on the web using freemysqlhosting.net‏. (*note: I can use any other remote db services, but it should be free, and I need it only for about a month*).
I have received the following details from freemysqlhosting.net‏:

```
Server: sql12.freemysqlhosting.net
Name, 
Username, 
Password and Port number.
```

After I will connect my c# project to the remote db, I plan to use entity framework in order to create the database automatically from the code.
I'm having trouble understanding how to connect my project to the remote database in a way that will later allow me to use entity framework.
Cheers :)

Comment: Entity framework is a long slog.  Consider using a micro-orm like Dapper instead.  Dapper can be connected directly to MySql; you just need the correct connection string.  EF is designed specifically for SQL Server.  If you still want to try to connect EF to SQL Server, look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: If i recall, the last time i worked with mysql and ef, there are limitations such as migrations doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps before starting your coding efforts you should check if you are able to reach their database services from outside their domain.